# Please remove revision-comment style from mod table

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, design

On the **History** tab of the moderator tools, there's a table that also lists my own user account. The row with my own user account in it has the CSS class `revision-comment` applied to it. Yet, it isn't a comment on a revision!

```
    <tbody>

        <tr class="revision-comment">
            <td class="user-info-td">
                <div style="position:relative;">

<div class="user-info user-hover">
    <div class="user-action-time">

    </div>
    <div class="user-gravatar32">
```

- This an issue because of my user style.
- Yes, I know it's unbelievably minor.
- Yes, I know it can be worked around.